# Any change to UITableViewCell remained for next loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mbprogresshud

I have a TableView. My question is why any changes to `UITableViewCell` is remained for next loads?

For example If I hide some view in some `UITableViewCell`, for next loadings of `UITableViewCell` this view still is in "hide" status:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString *cellID = @"SendID";

        MessagesTableViewCell *cell = (MessagesTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

       cell.myIcon.hidden = YES;
}
```

Another example is adding loader to a view of my cell and it is created for all next cells too:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString *cellID = @"SendID";

        MessagesTableViewCell *cell = (MessagesTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        MBProgressHUD *hud;
        hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:cell.imageView animated:YES];
        hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
        hud.labelText = @"Loading";
}
```

Is there any way to break this annoying way of loading cells? I need the fresh cell to be patterned for next loads of `UITableViewCell` without having performance issues (i.e. high memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called x number of times, where x is the number of rows or cells in the table view. So for each cell the method is called once. And what you are doing is hiding the icon or adding loader straight away in each call which makes it change every cell in the table view. If you want it to do for a particular cell, give a condition to check whether it is the required cell. For example, if you want to hide the icon only for cell at index 1, give

```
if(indexPath.row == 1) {
   cell. myIcon.hidden == YES;
} else {
   cell. myIcon.hidden == NO;
}
```

Comment: I know this and I do the same for my `UITableVIew`, but it does not change the behavior of `UITableView`. Any change to reusable cell will remain for all other loading of cells. I need the fresh cell to be patterned for next loads of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: You can give different patterns as required in an if-else condition and change the parameter by which you determine the pattern of the cell do that you don't need to get a fresh cell each time the cell is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should override `prepareForReuse` method of `UITableViewCell` and reset all your contents to defaults. This method is called each time the cell is being dequeued. Just set your code here to make your contents clear and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have fresh cells for each row, but that won't be much optimized.But there is a way to implement everything needed in efficient way.

I think, it is better to clear few things

Just a short overview, So you get your answer

UITableview is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UITableview, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

Now, you are updating the cells UI at runtime and thus the updated view gets cached for reuse.

Now, best way would be to use multiple instances of UITableViewCell for different kind of UI.

For instance, you wanted to have loader in a cell, then add another UITableViewCell with different identifier and use it for cells that need loading.

Ex.

```
if(loadedNeeded)
{
   MessagesTableViewCell *cell  = (MessagesTableViewCell *)[self.tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"loadedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
/*Add Loader programatically or add it in storyboard*/
  return cell;
} 
else
{
    MessagesTableViewCell *cell  = (MessagesTableViewCell *)[self.tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"plainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}
```

Now above code will keep two type of views in pool, one with identifier "loaderCell" and other "plainCell"

and you will get desired output.

But if you want to go for un-optimized way,

then don't use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method of UITableView and add your cell from nib or initiate it programatically, but not recommnended